# I cannot boot my Toshiba

Tags: windows, usb

I listened to my egghead hubby because he wanted to go back to Windows 7 from Windows 10.  Windows 7 had been preloaded to the laptop when purchased so we did not have a disc or even a recovery disc to go backwards.  We came across a website that allows you to download files to load Windows 7 provided you have a product key.  We tried to create a bootable usb and load it to the laptop but kept receiving an error message.  Hubby found some info about having the laptop automatically ask if it wanted to boot upon start up from usb or hard drive.  I followed his instructions and changed it in the BIOS advanced options.

Now, the damn laptop only boots up waiting for a bootable device and it is not reading the usb AT ALL.  Does anyone have any idea how I can break into the computer short of buying a windows disc to change it back to booting via hard drive???

I am at my wits end.  Hubby is in the doghouse over this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide us with error message

Answer (score 0):

To change boot settings, you'll need to go into the BIOS and change it to HDD in the same way that you changed it to USB.

As for creating a bootable USB disk, you can either use Rufus which can be found here: https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Or my favorite, ZOTAC, which can be found here: http://download.cnet.com/Zotac-WinUSB-Maker/3001-2242_4-76060668.html

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is you weren't successful in creating a bootable USB drive. Try using this software, it's worked for me before: https://rufus.akeo.ie/

You could also try burning the files onto a DVD disc and set the laptop to boot from CD drive.